# Laravel query where json array of objects contains

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a mysql table with a JSON column with data looking like that :

```
"[
{\"messageId\":\"0A0000000123ABCD1\",\"status\":\"request\\/0\",\"messagePrice\":\"0.03330000\"},            
{\"messageId\":\"0A0000000123ABCD2\",\"status\":\"request\\/0\",\"messagePrice\":\"0.03330000\"}
]"
```

How can I query the database to get the row containing a specific *messageId* (messageIds are uniques) ?

I tried :

```
DB::table('my_table')
 ->whereJsonContains('my_json_column',[['messageId'=>'0A0000000123ABCD1']]);
```

But I get no results.

**Edit :**
I can make it work with a simple where like :

```
DB::table('notification_history')
    ->where('nexmo_responses','like','%0A0000000123ABCD1%')
    ->get();
```

But it's not really a clean way to do it.

Comment: your data looks like it's been double-encoded when it was inserted. That's probably the real root of your issue.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks you, didn't think about that. I was saving an associative array with json_encode, I just remove the json_encode and it's working perfectly. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like it's been double-encoded when it was inserted. That's the root of your issue.

If you ensure the data is only encoded once, then it'll be readable correctly when you want to access it again.